# CallScreeningService get SIM-SLOT of Call in DUAL-SIM devices

Tags: android, android-service, call

I'm using Android-API 29 and my app is the default dialer-app on smartphones. On incoming calls my CallScreeningService-Class gets called (onScreenCall).

Unfortunately on Multi-SIM devices (like Dual-SIM) the Call.Details Object has no flag or attribute, where I can see on which SIM-Slot the actually incoming call is coming into. Here a short example:

```
public class IncomingCallService extends CallScreeningService {
@Override
public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
// HERE In callDetails I cant access to the flag if 
// the incoming call is coming on SIM-SLOT1 or SIM-SLOT2! 
}
```

Is there any alternative API working on all Dual SIM Phones or has every manufacturer its own?

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for an alternative API?

Comment: hi Simson, yes is there any alternative API working on all Dual SIM Phones or has every manufactur its own?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Nope, i am sorry! I think android doesn't allow it anymore since API 29